# Insert into Sql database in Intel-xdk

Tags: javascript, mysql, intel-xdk

I am developing a mobile app with Intel xdk, so I must use only javascript, HTML and CSS.

I am trying to communicate with a database which will insert user input into an SQL database. I realize that it will require php on the server.

I am looking for a sample code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:

First i have a html form on the page such as.

```
<form id="myForm" action="handler.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Age : <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
<button id="sub">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then on a linked javascript file, I have this code.

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
$.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
     });
clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
return false;
});
function clearInput() {
$("#myForm :input").each( function() {
   $(this).val('');
});
}
```

to connect with the database, the following code is put into the file db.php

```
<?php
  $conn = mysql_connect('serverName', 'username', 'password');
  $db   = mysql_select_db('databaseName');
?>
```

finally, the php file on the server (i.e handler.php) contains

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO sql_table_name(name, age) VALUES('$name', '$age')"))
     echo "Successfully Inserted";
    else
    echo "Insertion Failed";
?>
```

I found this [here](https://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/).

You can visit it for a better explanation with a video of the process.